# mysql insert problem

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to insert a MySQL row if some columns are empty?

Comment: please make an intelligle question

Comment: I took the liberty of editing your question trying to make it more understandable, feel free to re edit if that was not what you were asking. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible if they are not declared as `NOT NULL`

Comment: if you set a default value on the column, it's possible even on a column where NULL is allowed!

Comment: @Felix: Yes I Know That's why I just wrote `NOT NULL`

Answer (score 0):

Let's do an example:

Example `people` table (with a primary key `ID` column set to autoincrement):

```
ID    NAME    AGE
==    ====    ===
1     John    24
2     Jill    23
```

If you then wanted to insert a new record but did not know the age of a person, you could issue the following query:

```
INSERT INTO people
(NAME)
VALUES ('Jack');
```

This would result in:

```
ID    NAME    AGE
==    ====    ===
1     John    24
2     Jill    23
3     Jack
```

The requirement here is that the column either accept nulls or specify a default value. If `AGE` is `INT NULL` then the insert will work and a no value will be stored for Jack's age.

Alternatively you could specify that the `AGE` column have a default value, but this would probably be more appropriate for a field like `SCORE` where it's assumed new entries will start with some value (zero).